# Apple subscription - How to correctly configure the sandbox

Tags: ios, app-store, subscription

Is it possible to have a different App-Specific Shared Secret for the production and sandbox environment?

The same question for the Subscription Status URL. The App Store Connect UI seems to have only one text field for production and sandbox environment.

Comment: There is an option to regenerate the secret. will that work for you? Use the secret that you have now in sandbox. when you want to ship in production mode, regenerate the secret.

Comment: This work for now but then if I want to test and debug I have to use the production secret. That's not nice...

Comment: Can you get the secret dynamically through an API ?

Comment: I don't think so. This secret is used to access the api.

Comment: i was thinking that if you have integrated some API's in you app, then you have a server also. Ask your backend developer to write an api for you that returns the Shared secret. 

So, say, you have a shared secret `verySecretCode` in app store connect. You get that secret from your server through API request. (hard coded at bacend).

when you want to publish the app, regenerate the secret, put that new secret 'myNewSecret` in backend database. 

And your app will get the new secret through the same API request that you wrote earlier.